# Did Issei ever get to beat Vali?

Tags: high-school-dxd

If yes, did Issei beat Vali as well in their last duel in the canon?

Why I ask this question: Issei learned Vali's dividing trick, which seems to be a great boost to his superpower kit. I wonder if he's stronger than Vali later.

Answer (score 1):

In Volume 10, Issei and Vali duel to determine who will be the next heir to the throne of the Devil Kings. Issei is initially at a disadvantage, as Vali is much more experienced and powerful. However, Issei is able to turn the tide of the battle with the help of his friends and allies. In the end, Issei defeats Vali by using his newfound power, the Juggernaut Drive.

It is important to note that the anime adaptation of High School DxD does not follow the canon of the light novels. In the anime, Issei and Vali have a rematch in Season 3, and Issei is able to defeat Vali again. However, this is not considered to be canon, as it does not happen in the light novels.

Comment: Vali doesn't appear in volume 10 afair. Issei unlocks Cardinal Crimson Promotion towards the end of the novel, which is an upgraded form of Scale Mail and different path from the Juggernaut Drive. For the most part The anime is canon. The ending of Season 3 is not canon, as episode 0 of Season 4 retcons it. Season 4 should also cover volume 10 of the LN.